# Rolling Average, 1, 2, and 3 Lag of Statistics - R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

A picture of my dataset is below:
[image]

For each of the variables starting with HomeTeam and over I'm wanting to get a full time lagged rolling average, 1 record lagged average value, 2 records lagged average, and 3 records lagged average for each team. An Example of this is below that I've done in Excel for just the HomeTeam Variable for the 2016 Texas Tech Team.
[image]

Couple of Notes:

1. I will be needing to do this for every single variable from HomeTeam to the right. Obviously will not need it going left.
2. There is multiple years of data in this so we will need to group by Year and Team code in order to accurately do this.

Thanks ahead of time guys.

Comment: Hello Lcsballer1, welcome to SO. To help us help you, please offer a reproducible example, it can be a sample of your original data. The function `dput()` might help you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hey @Nicolás Velásquez, what is the difference between a reproducible example and the example picture I provided?

Comment: See how in my answer df_games is set as a reproducible example? It does help a lot to test the code. Again, dput() is a very handy function in R to obtain a reproducible code of a dataset or other types of object.

Comment: I see ok that makes sense. I apologize for not having that the first time around. This code worked awesome! Thank you so much for putting this together. I only had one further question though. If I were to get one more column that is the average of all the lagged values so not 1 2 or 3 but of every data point we have could I just add another row to the mutate function with the k value not filled in? @Nicolás Velásquez

Comment: No problem, my friend. You will see that any question with a reproducible example gets more and quicker answers around here. Regarding your average question, you want a rowwise or a column wise mean? That is, a mean of log_01, Log_02, log_03 for each observation, or a mean of log_01 and log_02, and log_03 for the same team?

Comment: Not the mean of the logs, just truly a rolling mean for the team for that specific year. For example. Week 2 will be a lag 1, week 3 lag 2, week 4 lag 3, week 5 lag 4 all the way up to their last game of the example. It's essentially a rolling mean with a maximum lag. Sorry if this is still not making sense. @Nicolás Velásquez

Comment: I see, a cumulative mean up to that week.  What if there are multiple games in the same week?  Is that a possibility?

Comment: @Nicolás Velásquez, there would never be any time a team would be play twice in the same day. So we would just need to take a cumulative mean for every date before the date of the record in question.

Comment: All right, I added a lagged `cummean()` line in the mutate block to get just that.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much Nicolas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With made-up + cheaply OCRed data (which I would happily update when the OP gives us a reproducible example):

With `tidyverse` for wrangling and pivoting, and `zoo` for rolled means, try,

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

df_games <- 
  tibble(game_code = c(1:21), 
         team_code = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
         opponent_code = c(231, 306, 129, 27, 694, 277, 107, 1320, 440, 314, 465, 380, 164, 295, 528, 428, 458, 367, 736, 574, 772), 
         year = 2016, 
         date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2016-01-01"), by = 7, length.out = 21),
         team = c("TA", "TA", "TA", "TA", "TA", "TA", "TA", "TA", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TC", "TC", "TC", "TC", "TC", "TC", "TC"), 
         opp = c("FI", "I", "CM", "AS", "T", "Hi", "C", "P", "MS", "JS", "U", "M", "C", "I2", "OS", "M", "C2", "L", "V","R", "WK"), 
         home_team = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
         points = c(34, 13, 3, 20, 13, 51, 31, 49, 20, 63, 13, 24, 21, 17, 30, 23, 70, 14, 13, 46, 14), 
         opp_points = c(13, 34, 49, 13, 20, 31, 51, 3, 17, 13, 63, 21, 24, 20, 23, 30, 14, 70, 10, 14, 46), 
         total = c(47, 47, 52, 33, 33, 82, 82, 52, 37, 76, 76, 45, 45, 37, 53, 53, 84, 84, 23, 60, 60), 
         mov = c(-21, 21, 46, -7, 7, -20, 20, -46, -3, -50, 50, -3, 3, 3, -7, 7, -56, 56, -3, -32, 32), 
         spread = c(-4, 4, 32, -22.5, 22.5, -22, 22, -32.1, -6.5, -40, 40, -27, 27, 65, -9.5, 9.5, -38.5, 38.5, 2.5, -16.5, 16.5), 
         book_total = c(61, 61, 52, 56, 56, 63, 63, 52, 37, 76, 76, 45, 45, 37, 57, 57, 59.5, 59.5, 46.5, 60, 60), 
         book_pts = c(32.5, 28.5, 10, 39.25, 16.75, 42.5, 20.5, 42, 21.75, 58, 18, 36, 9, 15.25, 33.25, 23.75, 49, 10.5, 22, 38.25, 21.75), 
         book_opp_pts = c(28.5, 32.5, 42, 16.75, 39.25, 20.5, 42.5, 10, 15.25, 18, 58, 9, 36, 21.75, 23.75, 33.25, 10.5, 49, 24.5, 21.75, 38.25), 
         rush_att = c(52, 21, 33, 43, 43, 35, 38, 38, 35, 44, 35, 50, 19, 38, 47, 34, 35, 31, 32, 30, 33), 
         rush_yard = c(246, 63, 44, 127, 184, 189, 248, 255, 225, 280, 108, 200, 40, 105, 150, 89, 272, 48, 121, 97, 105))


df_games %>% 
  pivot_longer(# Here we pivot from wide format into long format in order to efficiently create all the lagged values with a single call for all variables
    cols = !c(game_code:home_team), names_to = "metric", values_to = "values") %>% 
  arrange(team_code, metric, date) %>% 
  group_by(team_code, year, metric) %>% #The next lines create the lagged means
  mutate(cumean = lag(cummean(values)), # Here is the grouped cumulative mean up to that match
         lag_01 = zoo::rollmean(x = values, k = 2, fill = NA, align = "right"),
         lag_02 = zoo::rollmean(x = values, k = 3, fill = NA, align = "right"),
         lag_03 = zoo::rollmean(x = values, k = 4, fill = NA, align = "right")) %>% 
  select(-values) %>%
  pivot_wider(#Here we pivot back into wide format.
    names_from = metric, values_from = c(lag_01:lag_03)) %>% arrange(team_code, date)

# A tibble: 21 x 48
# Groups:   team_code, year [3]
   game_code team_code opponent_code  year date       team  opp   home_team cumean_book_opp_pts cumean_book_pts
       <int>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <chr> <chr>     <dbl>               <dbl>           <dbl>
 1         1         1           231  2016 2016-01-01 TA    FI            0                NA              NA  
 2         2         1           306  2016 2016-01-08 TA    I             1                28.5            32.5
 3         3         1           129  2016 2016-01-15 TA    CM            0                30.5            30.5
 4         4         1            27  2016 2016-01-22 TA    AS            1                34.3            23.7
 5         5         1           694  2016 2016-01-29 TA    T             0                29.9            27.6
 6         6         1           277  2016 2016-02-05 TA    Hi            0                31.8            25.4
 7         7         1           107  2016 2016-02-12 TA    C             0                29.9            28.2
 8         8         1          1320  2016 2016-02-19 TA    P             1                31.7            27.1
 9         9         2           440  2016 2016-02-26 TB    MS            1                NA              NA  
10        10         2           314  2016 2016-03-04 TB    JS            1                15.2            21.8
# ... with 11 more rows, and 38 more variables: cumean_book_total <dbl>, cumean_mov <dbl>,
#   cumean_opp_points <dbl>, cumean_points <dbl>, cumean_rush_att <dbl>, cumean_rush_yard <dbl>,
#   cumean_spread <dbl>, cumean_total <dbl>, lag_01_book_opp_pts <dbl>, lag_01_book_pts <dbl>,
#   lag_01_book_total <dbl>, lag_01_mov <dbl>, lag_01_opp_points <dbl>, lag_01_points <dbl>,
#   lag_01_rush_att <dbl>, lag_01_rush_yard <dbl>, lag_01_spread <dbl>, lag_01_total <dbl>,
#   lag_02_book_opp_pts <dbl>, lag_02_book_pts <dbl>, lag_02_book_total <dbl>, lag_02_mov <dbl>,
#   lag_02_opp_points <dbl>, lag_02_points <dbl>, lag_02_rush_att <dbl>, lag_02_rush_yard <dbl>,
#   lag_02_spread <dbl>, lag_02_total <dbl>, lag_03_book_opp_pts <dbl>, lag_03_book_pts <dbl>,
#   lag_03_book_total <dbl>, lag_03_mov <dbl>, lag_03_opp_points <dbl>, lag_03_points <dbl>,
#   lag_03_rush_att <dbl>, lag_03_rush_yard <dbl>, lag_03_spread <dbl>, lag_03_total <dbl>
```

Comment: `rollmean(..., align = "right")` can be shortened slightly to `rollmeanr(...)` with an `r` on the end.